# Why were the "infiltrator" T101 units built on such a conspicious body?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

It was noted that the Terminators (T101) were **infiltrator** units, designed to infiltrate the resistance.

Given the ragged undernourished humans of the time, wouldn't making an infiltrator body into the hulking over-built Conan The Destroyer frame be something totally illogical if your goal is to blend in?

Why not use a more "normal" body? Robots already have metal frame and super-strong muscles, so size wasn't required to bump the combat capacity as with flesh and bone humans.

Comment: It all depends where they were first intended on infiltrating. It would fit right in as governor of California...

Comment: Related question. Not a duplicate. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151049/why-didnt-kyle-reese-know-what-the-terminator-looked-like-in-the-original-movie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the original Terminator we see two different models.

The Terminator in the future:

[image]

And the Terminator in the present day:

[image]

In the Sarah Connor Chronicles there were a variety of body types.

[Cromartie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromartie_%28Terminator%29#Cromartie) is different from the terminator [Carter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromartie_%28Terminator%29#Carter) as Cameron (another body type and model) identifies his endoskeletal structure as different.

> Cameron: That's not Cromartie. Endoskeletal structure points don't match. He's too short.

Carter:

[image]

Here is Cameron vs Cromartie:

[image]

Here is Cameron vs Rosie (the Terminator):

[image]

From this we can see there are a wide variety of terminator chasis for blending in.

Answer (score 9):

There is a [deleted scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kayFrIR-Qfw) in Terminator 3 that explains why the Terminator 101 units look like they do. Essentially "Sergeant Candy" (portrayed by Arnold with a horrifyingly obvious dubbed Southern Accent) was chosen to be the "model" for the T101 unit.

Note: As Xantec pointed out in a comment, Kyle had a flashback in Terminator. The flashback shows a non-Arnold version terminator infiltrating a human controlled base. This seems to indicate that they *did* change the look of the units, at least from time to time. Since we see more than one "Arnold" version, it is likely that there is a (limited) pool from which they can select a unit.

[This YouTube playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0FC509C0CAEC6005) has (supposedly) all of the Terminator units from all of the films and the TV series, so there is quite a variety.

Comment: There was another non-Arnold version portrayed in Terminator, during one of Kyle's flashbacks.

Comment: If you include the TV series, Terminators came in a variety of visual models (maybe as many as 101).

Comment: @JackBNimble - if you have screenshots of them being smalled bodied, that'd be a good answer.

Comment: @Xantec - the other terminator was played by Arnold's bodybuilding buddy, Franco Columbu. He shows up in the documentary Pumping Iron, as well.

Comment: @DVK I think Jack B Nimble's answer should be the accepted one, he did more work on it than I did, and in fact the only reason my answer contains other versions is from Xantec's comments.

Comment: @NominSim - the accept was for the youtube list, but I basically liked BOTH answers equally and more or less was close to flipping the coin. Since you prefer Jack's asnwer I will follow that preference and change the accept - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The T800 series exo skeleton was one of the earliest models. It was originally used on the battlefield and **retrofitted** for use as an infiltrator.

So it had big robotics for being a battlefield soldier, then had skin (or rubber) just plastered over the top. It looked so big because it WAS so big.

Later models (T-1000, etc) used more advanced technology that allowed them to be smaller or have better control over their shape.

Answer (score 0):

The models you're comparing are all T-888s if I recall correctly. The T-800 all looked like Arnold in order to give a body size large enough to house the terminator skeleton. Where as the T888 were more advanced and smaller, better able to blend in without looking like a giant Austrian