# Where was the likeness of the T-1000 taken from?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In *Terminator 2: Judgment Day*, the T-1000 appears on the scene in the form of actor Robert Patrick. It then slaughters an investigating police officer, mimics his clothes, and steals the police car.

My question is where the Robert Patrick appearance came from. Did Skynet create this likeness for the T-1000? Was the Patrick look-alike an actual human being, whom Skynet copied?

Comment: To balance the [Southern-accented T-800 sergeant](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22150/976), must have been a Yankee Colonel.

Comment: Related : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kayFrIR-Qfw

Comment: The fact that your name is T-1000 somewhat vexes me...

Answer (score 6):

Within the Judgment Day film (and the film's novelisation) there are no indications who the T-1000 was based on. He's simply described as having...

> *...a handsome face, with strong features framed by military-short
> brown hair. His gray-blue eyes were furrowed with deep concentration,
> confident.* - <sub><sup>[Randall Frakes - Terminator : Judgement Day](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

and

> *A NAKED MAN glides from a shadowed doorway behind the cop.  Nothing special about him.  Certainly not built like a terminator.  The flash
> of light and fact that he is naked are pretty good clues that he just
> arrived from the future.  His features are handsome bordering on
> severe.  His eyes are gray ice.  Penetrating.  Intelligent.*-
> <sub><sup>[Terminator : Judgement Day Screenplay](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SjMujmfSt98J:www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)</sup></sub>

---

The director of the fourth Terminator film (McG) spoke about the idea of incorporating an older Robert Patrick into his next film as a scientist who is working on nano-technology:

> **TheArnoldFans:** *Will we possibly have a return of Robert Patrick in a CG form?*
>
> **McG:** *Funny, I talk to Robert Patrick with great regularity. It's interesting and i'll bounce it off of you guys (McG begins to lower
> his voice and leans in closer to me so the other press tables don't
> hear). I mean, I like the idea and the perspective for the next
> picture that you meet Robert Patrick the way he looks today...and he's
> a scientist that's working on, you know, improving cell replication so
> we can stay healthier and we can cure diabetes and do all these things
> that sound like good ideas...and to once again live as idealized
> expressions as ourselves.*
>
> *So imagine seeing a 60-year-old Robert Patrick and KNOWING 'holy shit' that's GOING TO BE the T-1000 who comes back perfect, lean and
> the whole thing (McG makes the T-1000 "naughty naughty" finger swaying
> movement). I haven't concluded that but Robert and I had dinner the
> other night.* - <sub><sup>[TheArnoldFans ComicCon Interview](http://archive.thearnoldfans.com/news/1421.htm)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

If I had to make a guess, it was probably a humanoid shape based on individuals that Skynet probably had in its database at the time. Think about it. It comes out of the Time Machine like that and that is ALWAYS its default form. To say what it is not, it certainly could not have taken that shape after sampling someone because it would need to revert back to that shape. The figure would have to be someone that it has to revert back to in its original programming via the time it was made.

Comment: This answer seems like little better than guesswork.

Comment: Valorum: Of course it is not the correct answer, but a very educated assumption. We always see it change into this metallic humanoid form, every time, before it changes into the Robert Patrick form. Most people on here follow it up with evidence and I would say "Watch the movie!"

Comment: I'm assuming OP already watched the movie.

Comment: Valorum: No, I mean it as a general "Watch the movie, as many times as necessary, to figure the answer yourself."